# How can I display/hide a component depending on a property on the Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, store

I am studying Redux but I'm having problems to understand it properly.
Now I am building a personal project with it to learn it.

I have this "Settings button" (actually, it is a list item) on the navbar. When I click it, I want that another component shows itself. This will be the `<Settings />` component. This component has a "Close button" to hide.

My idea is to have a property on the redux global store like this: `settingsOpen: false` and when I click on the button it becomes true and the component appears and vice-versa. The close button always set the property equal to false and close the component.

Here you can find all the code: https://github.com/lbluigi/react-ecommerce

Anyway, I think the important parts are:

**Header.js component**

This is the list item clicked that would toggle the Settings component.

```
<a onClick={(event) => this.props.toggleSettings(event)} href="#settings" className="nav-link"><i className="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i> Settings</a>
```

**Settings.js component**

This is the component that had to appear and disappear depending on the `settingsOpens` property.

```
<div className={this.props.settings.settingsOpen ? 'settings' : 'hidden'}>
  <i className="fa fa-times fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  {/* just a test <h2>{this.props.settings.themeColor}</h2> */}
</div>
```

**toggleSettings.js action**
This is the function triggered by the click event on the settings button that I wrote before.

```
event.preventDefault();
return {
  type: 'SETTINGS_TOGGLED'
}
```

**settingsReducer.js reducer**

This is the reducer that sets the initial properties that the user can change interacting with the Settings component.

```
{
  settingsOpen: false,
  themeColor: 'light',
  gridView: 'grid'
}
```

I could write a lot more, but you will find everything on the GitHub repo that I linked before. I don't know how to proceed to change the property `settingsOpen` on click.

Comment: Can you post the full files? What does `toggleSettings` do? What do your render methods look like? Where are you dispatching your action to the store? No one wants to go to your github and dig through your repo just to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `settingsReducer` must be a function which returns an object (state) by dispatching actions. In your case it should be:

```
const defaultSettings = {settingsOpen: false, themeColor: 'light'}
const settingsReducer = (state = defaultSettings, action) {
  if (action.type === 'SETTINGS_TOGGLED') {
    return {
      ...state,
      settingsOpen: !state.settingsOpen
    }
  }
  return state
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I spent hours to figure it out and it was so easy. Redux tutorials are so weird. Now I understood that I need to define a defaultSettings object.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wq24zkkrvw

Basically I initialised the store with a isOpen=false
and every time you click on the button toggles the value of this.

reducer:

```
const initState = {
  isOpen: false
};
export default (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE':
      return { isOpen: !state.isOpen };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and this is the component that will dispatch the action:

```
<Counter
      isOpen={store.getState().isOpen}
      onToggle={() => store.dispatch({ type: 'TOGGLE' })}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change some store property over time - you'll need a reducer. Because reducer is function that responsible for store mutations (changes). You already have one but it always return same value.

```js
function settingsReducer() {
  return {
    settingsOpen: false,
    color: 'light',
    view: 'grid'
  }
}
```

Firstly you'll have to modify it in order to add reaction - `once action appear, i would want to modify store like this:`,

```js
function settingsReducer(state, action) {
    if (action.type === 'SETTINGS_TOGGLED') {
      return {
        settingsOpen: !state.settingsOpen,
        color: 'light',
        view: 'grid',
      };
    }
    return {
      settingsOpen: false,
      color: 'light',
      view: 'grid',
    };
  }
```

At that point you would have to create(define) an [action](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html#action-creators).

After that proceed to  a link in your header and add [dispatch](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch) of an action instead returning value. Note that you have to [connect](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html) `header` component for dispatching. Now your action will appear inside reducer and would be able to o modify store
You can use some kind of a [logger](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger) to check what is happening in your system
After you make sure state is changing  as you planned - you'd need to [connect](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html) a `Settings` component to a store to pass `settingsOpen` property from store to component.

Thats where you return to you Settings component again, but from different side. Thinking in redux is always like this - you have to plan and implement whole loop. Somethink like: `component handles click` -> `action` -> `reducer` -> `store changes` -> `component` -> `render changes`